# After domain registration at Namecheap, is the default parked domain page bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, google, domains

I bought a domain from Namecheap 2 week ago, but right now don't not use this domain. This domain is indexed by Google, but it currently holds some default Namecheap message.

Does this Namecheap default page have a negative effect on Google rankings or in meantime get some Google penalty because of thin content? I plan to leave this website there for several months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving a domain parked at the domain registrar after registration won't hurt your eventual rankings in any way.   Leaving a domain name with a default page at the domain registrar is very common.  Pretty much all domains are in this state for at least a short amount of time.   Many are left there for months or years.

Google doesn't want to index the site while it is parked at the domain registrar.  [Google says](https://www.google.com/insidesearch/howsearchworks/fighting-spam.html):

> #### Parked domains
>
> Parked domains are placeholder sites with little unique content, so Google doesn’t typically include them in search results.

However, once you put your own content on that domain, Google will crawl it again and immediately notice that it is no longer parked.   At that point, Google will index your content just fine.

Googlebot has special code to help it identify parked domains.  It will choose not to index the domain while parked, but no penalties are applied against the domain.  You will be able to get it ranked again at any point you choose to unpark it.

Comment: Great find about Parked domain.

Answer (score 0):

I (We) don't know how Google treat new register domain or parked domain webpages like above you said, but why just don't redirect that domain to some other website, like Google.com or something other website. That things you can setup through your domain panel without using any hosting service, and once your site is ready, just remove that redirection. That is what I will recommended it.

Comment: So you recommended that redirect page to google.com so when I click on my page it will open google.com?

Comment: I mean when you open your new domain then it redirect to Google. If you mean same by click then yes. And Googlebot will also treat same redirection. If you have hosting then you can block crawler from indexing it via robotos.txt or meta tags. But the quickest way is to setup redirection from domain control panel.

Comment: redirection to google or some other domain not give some penalty?

Comment: No, it does not give you any penalty.

Comment: Leaving a domain name parked seems much safer than redirecting it to Google to me.

Comment: Yes, it might be safer, but setting redirection also not heart in SEO.