# I turned off domain parking and my domain is no longer available. Is that bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, google, domains, parking

After I registered domain their was parked, but I turn off parking.  Now the domain not available at all.  Will this somehow have a bad affect on SEO or risk some Google penalty?

I want leave this domain alone for some time, after which I will point  it to my hosting and use it.

Comment: For reference, a related question asked by the same person earlier: [After domain registration at Namecheap, is the default parked domain page bad for SEO?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/100692/after-domain-registration-at-namecheap-is-the-default-parked-domain-page-bad-fo)

Comment: this is not same, because here i ask what if i turn off parking and leave domain not available, will this affect somehow on seo or give some penalty, on question which you paste i ask what happend if is domain parking

Comment: I agree it is not the same.    I included it for reference, but I did not suggest that it is duplicate.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller can you please check my replay on marcanuy answer, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning off a parked domain doesn't affect the domain reputation at all, in fact, parked domains are pretty much ignored by Google and are not likely to appear in search results because they do not provide any value to an end user.

Once you set a real website in the domain it will start getting indexed.

Search Console support confirm this:

> parked pages don't provide value to searchers, so we don't typically
>   return them in our search results. If you have parked domains,
>   activate the domains and fill them with useful content to make them
>   eligible for being indexed and returned in search results

Comment: so if i understand after registration if i leave domain not available will not affect bad on seo or give me some google penalty same like domain is parking also not affect on seo and not give me penalty, google will not show this both domain in index, but not penalty, when i open domain and add content google will normal index this domain?

Comment: @nikola99 yes, first of all, if you don't explictely put a link to the new domain It will be very unlikely that Google even knows that it exists, if it ends up crawling it, will detect a parked domain and ignore them until new content is found. Anyway I would too turn it off as you did.

Comment: so you more prefer turn off domain parking and add domain not available for time when you not use that?

Comment: @nikola99 yes, I prefer to turn it off, never had problems with that.

Comment: I agree with this answer.  Like domain parking, Google will not penalize a new domain that does not resolve.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller what is better after registration leave domain parking or turn off parking and leave domain not available?

Comment: Doesn't matter.   Google treats them pretty much the same.